# Is it required to remove from both sides of an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I have two models, associated via an `has_and_belongs_to_many` association. I want to destroy the association between the two objects but not delete the objects themselves. Is there an easier way to do it than the following?

```
list = List.find(params[:list_id])
contact = Contact.find(params[:contact_id])

list.contacts.delete contact
contact.contact_lists.delete list

list.save
contact.save
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `has_and_belongs_to_many`, the association record is in a join table e.g. lists_contacts. So just one side of the operation such as `list.contacts.delete contact` will delete that row and is enough.

For example:

```
list = List.create
contact = Contact.create
list.contacts << contact
list.save
p contact.lists # => [#<List id: 5, name: nil>]
list.contacts.delete contact
list.save
p contact.reload.lists # => []
```

Comment: Thanks much. :) Also reminded me that I would need to reload things in other places in the controller. D'oh.